# HTTP PUT to upload a file in Java

Tags: java, file-upload, vimeo, http-put, scribe

**Edit:** I think I've figured out how to do the binary data part. Double check it in the code, but I'm pretty sure I've got it right. Now I'm getting a new error when trying to complete the upload as described in the [Vimeo API documentation](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/upload#streaming)

**Edit 2:** Added .debug() to the OAuthService and updated the output.

**Original Question**: I'm trying to upload a video to Vimeo using the [Vimeo API (Streaming Method)](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/upload#streaming). I'm using [scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) to authorize my app, get my access token and prepare for the video upload. I just don't know what to do at the point the Vimeo API documentation says "binary data of your file here" in this example of a HTTP request for the PUT:

> PUT http://1.2.3.4:8080/upload?ticket_id=abcdef124567890 HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: 1.2.3.4:8080
>
> Content-Length: 339108
>
> Content-Type: video/mp4
>
> .... binary data of your file here ....

I can get the ticket and headers fine. It's just, what do I do to insert the binary data of my file?

Notes:

- It's a desktop app in Java
- It's a small video file I'm testing

Here's my code for the put (remember, I'm using [scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java))

```
// Setup File (line 52)
File testUp = new File("C:/Users/Kent/Desktop/test.mp4");
String contentLength = Long.toString(testUp.length());
System.out.println("The content length is: " + contentLength);
byte[] fileBytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(testUp));

// Upload file (line 58)
request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.PUT, endpoint);
request.addHeader("Content-Length", contentLength);
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
request.addPayload(fileBytes);
response = signSendAndPrint(service, accessToken, request, "Upload PUT: " + endpoint);

// Check response code is valid (line 65)
if (response.getCode() != 200) {
  System.out.println("The response was not 200! It was: " + response.getCode());
  return;
}

// Verify the upload (line 71)
request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.PUT, endpoint);
request.addHeader("Content-Length", "0");
request.addHeader("Content-Range", "bytes */*");
response = signSendAndPrint(service, accessToken, request, "Verify Upload PUT: " + endpoint);

// Check response code is valid (line 77)
if (response.getCode() != 308) {
  System.out.println("The response was not 308! It was: " + response.getCode());
  return;
}

// Complete Upload (line 83)
request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.PUT, endpoint);
request.addQuerystringParameter("method", "vimeo.videos.upload.complete");
Response completeResponse = signSendAndPrint(service, accessToken, request, "complete"); // This is line 86, it's the second to top level of my code that breaks the process.

//Set video info (line 88)
setVimeoVideoInfo(completeResponse, service, accessToken, vimeoAPIURL);
  }



/**
   * Signs the request on the service, prints information on the request, sends the request, prints
   * information on the response and returns the response
   *
   * @param service
   * @param accessToken
   * @param request
   * @param description
   * @return
   */
  private static Response signSendAndPrint(OAuthService service, Token accessToken, OAuthRequest request, String description) {
    service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
    printRequest(request, description + " Request");
    Response response = request.send(); //This is line 105. It's the top level of my code that breaks the process
    printResponse(response, description + " Response");
    return response;
  }
```

Output of the `signSendAndPrint(OAuthService service, Token accessToken, OAuthRequest request, String description)` method and on the `OAuthService.debug()`:

```
Upload PUT: http://174.129.155.54:8080/upload?ticket_id=a64ed67b4aefdc35d18aec6cfa0b7c5e Request
Headers: {Authorization=OAuth oauth_signature="MTPIVFfGVUQn4QswNV6av4CjzJw%3D", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_nonce="-606493399", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key="MY_CONSUMER_KEY", oauth_token="MY_OAUTH_TOKEN", oauth_timestamp="1332428103", Content-Length=15125120, Content-Type=video/mp4}
Verb: PUT
Complete URL: http://174.129.155.54:8080/upload?ticket_id=a64ed67b4aefdc35d18aec6cfa0b7c5e

Upload PUT: http://174.129.155.54:8080/upload?ticket_id=a64ed67b4aefdc35d18aec6cfa0b7c5e Response
Code: 200
Headers: {null=HTTP/1.1 200 OK, Content-Length=0, Connection=close, Content-Type=text/plain, Server=Vimeo/1.0}
Body: 
signing request: http://174.129.155.54:8080/upload?ticket_id=a64ed67b4aefdc35d18aec6cfa0b7c5e
setting token to: Token[87bddf1382ac9f423d4b7c4166bdf0b2 , fdae7a033c7e1c932abce533627d6045124e8593]
generating signature...
base string is: PUT&http%3A%2F%2F174.129.155.54%3A8080%2Fupload&oauth_consumer_key%3DMY_CONSUMER_KEY%26oauth_nonce%3D1585934110%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1332428110%26oauth_token%3DMY_OAUTH_TOKEN%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26ticket_id%3Da64ed67b4aefdc35d18aec6cfa0b7c5e
signature is: bhWu7IX9JKEEn/ULcpJECEuwqOc=
appended additional OAuth parameters: { oauth_signature -> bhWu7IX9JKEEn/ULcpJECEuwqOc= , oauth_version -> 1.0 , oauth_nonce -> 1585934110 , oauth_signature_method -> HMAC-SHA1 , oauth_consumer_key -> MY_CONSUMER_KEY, oauth_token -> MY_OAUTH_TOKEN, oauth_timestamp -> 1332428110 }
using Http Header signature

Verify Upload PUT: http://174.129.155.54:8080/upload?ticket_id=a64ed67b4aefdc35d18aec6cfa0b7c5e Request
Headers: {Authorization=OAuth oauth_signature="bhWu7IX9JKEEn%2FULcpJECEuwqOc%3D", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_nonce="1585934110", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key="MY_CONSUMER_KEY", oauth_token="MY_OAUTH_TOKEN", oauth_timestamp="1332428110", Content-Length=0, Content-Range=bytes */*} *///Note, this is not part of the output, I just added */// so the rest of it doesn't appear commented out.
Verb: PUT
Complete URL: http://174.129.155.54:8080/upload?ticket_id=a64ed67b4aefdc35d18aec6cfa0b7c5e

Verify Upload PUT: http://174.129.155.54:8080/upload?ticket_id=a64ed67b4aefdc35d18aec6cfa0b7c5e Response
Code: 308
Headers: {null=HTTP/1.1 308 Resume Incomplete, Range=bytes=0-15125119, Content-Length=0, Connection=close, Content-Type=text/plain, Server=Vimeo/1.0}
Body: 
signing request: http://174.129.155.54:8080/upload?ticket_id=a64ed67b4aefdc35d18aec6cfa0b7c5e&method=vimeo.videos.upload.complete
setting token to: Token[87bddf1382ac9f423d4b7c4166bdf0b2 , fdae7a033c7e1c932abce533627d6045124e8593]
generating signature...
base string is: PUT&http%3A%2F%2F174.129.155.54%3A8080%2Fupload&method%3Dvimeo.videos.upload.complete%26oauth_consumer_key%3DMY_CONSUMER_KEY%26oauth_nonce%3D3111236130%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1332428110%26oauth_token%3DMY_OAUTH_TOKEN%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26ticket_id%3Da64ed67b4aefdc35d18aec6cfa0b7c5e
signature is: vXlQ6OUKms8eHan+wEBO2HXBn/M=
appended additional OAuth parameters: { oauth_signature -> vXlQ6OUKms8eHan+wEBO2HXBn/M= , oauth_version -> 1.0 , oauth_nonce -> 3111236130 , oauth_signature_method -> HMAC-SHA1 , oauth_consumer_key -> MY_CONSUMER_KEY, oauth_token -> MY_OAUTH_TOKEN, oauth_timestamp -> 1332428110 }
using Http Header signature

complete Request
Headers: {Authorization=OAuth oauth_signature="vXlQ6OUKms8eHan%2BwEBO2HXBn%2FM%3D", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_nonce="3111236130", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key="MY_CONSUMER_KEY", oauth_token="MY_OAUTH_TOKEN", oauth_timestamp="1332428110"}
Verb: PUT
Complete URL: http://174.129.155.54:8080/upload?ticket_id=a64ed67b4aefdc35d18aec6cfa0b7c5e&method=vimeo.videos.upload.complete
Exception in thread "main" org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Problems while creating connection.
    at org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:70)
    at org.scribe.model.OAuthRequest.send(OAuthRequest.java:12)
    at autouploadermodel.VimeoTest.signSendAndPrint(VimeoTest.java:105)
    at autouploadermodel.VimeoTest.main(VimeoTest.java:86)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:723)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:589)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:720)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:589)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1319)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at org.scribe.model.Response.<init>(Response.java:28)
    at org.scribe.model.Request.doSend(Request.java:110)
    at org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:62)
    ... 3 more
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append two other parameters when completing the upload. [Vimeo API documentation](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/methods/vimeo.videos.upload.complete) says you need three parameters for vimeo.videos.upload.complete: filename, oauth_token and ticket_id. scribe takes care of the oauth_token for you.

Furthermore, you have to call the original endpoint, not the one obtained when requesting a ticket.

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly! Thank you very much. I can't believe it was so simple, but that's the way it is half the time. Thanks again :)