# how to upload video to vimeo through android app?

Tags: android, vimeo

I am new to Android. I am doing a application in which I want to upload a video to Vimeo using Vimeo API from my app. I tried googling,but I cannot find any good explanation. In Vimeo developers link, they only provided some method names and parameters, no examples.

Can anyone guide me to a good tutorial or suggest me some sample codes to work on. Also I cannot find any Vimeo libraries for android. Please suggest some libraries compatible with Android. Any help in this case is appreciable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i also have same task to do (upload video to vimeo via my android app). Googled about it but did not found anything helpfull . If you have done that , please guide me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Just see the links below and follow the steps in  https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/upload

[1] [HTTP PUT to upload a file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773705/http-put-to-upload-a-file-in-java)

[2] http://pastebin.com/79iSxzmR

Note:- i used scribe library at https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java which provides with methods used in above links [1] and [2].

Comment: I'm sorry if this breaks stackoverflow convention, but I just wanted to let you know that I came across your java source randomly on pastebin.  It saved me so much time that I decided I had to find out who wrote it, and just stop by to say THANK YOU! :)

Comment: am getting <err code="401" expl="The oauth_token passed was either not valid or has expired." msg="Permission Denied"/>
.. how can i solve this..

Answer (score 0):

To upload videos to vimeo ,one needs to have an authenticated access token.

Answer (score -1):

Please visit http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/simple and explore the API available there to make your task easy you